# MessageBoxShow on launch of the application

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

How to show the message box as soon as the application is launched.
I would like to add a welcome message in my application.
Eg:
MessageBox.Show("Welcome");

Comment: Why a MessageBox?  Just incorporate your welcome on your opening screen, if at all. As a user of your app, I wouldn't want my initial experience to be a message box that really doesn't add any feature to the app.  If you must though, you could include in OnNavigatedTo() of your start page, and display only when NavigationMode is New.

Comment: @JimO'Neil Thanks for the feedback. But the welcome screen last for few seconds. I want the user to read it. In case he is not interested he can turn of the message. Increasing the time of welcome screen without a OK button might annoy the user.

Comment: I'm not sure that it will be certified by M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Call the Show(String) method from the
>   OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs) method. If you call Show(String)
>   method from the app Activated and Launching event handlers an
>   InvalidOperationException is thrown with the message Error Displaying
>   MessageBox."

MSDN Source @  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206947(v=vs.105).aspx